# How to remove header border of webview in android

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to remove the header border of a `WebView` in an Android app.To clarify, lets see an image:

[image: Description: Screenshot of Android Emulator. Empty title bar highlighted with a red rectangle, above a web view containing a web page for Morena Pantry]

Now, in this image I highlight the header of the site with a red border. I want to remove that header border block.

Here is my Android code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package in.co.morenapantry.morenapantry;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView2);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("url");

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="in.co.morenapantry.morenapantry">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label=""
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just open styles.xml in AppTheme add this**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no toolbar/header in xml which you posted xml contains web view . 
Then how the green header/ toolbar is loading ?

Check once your color file and color primary, color primary dark colors.[image]

I opened your webview loading url in browser it should open like this according to your xml or code ?

Check below tutorial for web view implementation.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.androidhive.info/2016/12/android-working-with-webview-building-a-simple-in-app-browser/amp/

Answer (score 0):

add your manifest to this part.Change your activity theme style using below code.

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> 
    </activity>
```